# How do I search and replace a string after an arbitrary amount of white space in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, perl, search, replace

I’m using bash shell.  I have a text file containing only the line

```
name           "Test Program"
```

I would like to add curly braces around the string after name, making the file look like

```
name           { “Test Program" }
```

I tried the below expression

```
perl -pi -e 's/name(\s+)"(.*)"/name$1{ "$2" }/g' /tmp/test.txt
```

But ended up with a file containing only

```
name
```

Am I misunderstanding something about the arbitrary white space (\s) or substituting?

Comment: `sed 's/".*"/{ & }/' file`?

Comment: I assume `“` should be `"`.

Comment: Escape the curly brackets in your perl command: `perl -pi -e 's/name(\s+)"(.*)"/name$1\{ "$2" \}/g' /tmp/test.txt`

Comment: @Dave: What do you mean by **arbitrary** whitespace? In a Perl regexp, a `\s` represents a single white space character (space, or tab or newline).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
perl -pi -e 's/name(\s+)"(.*)"/name$1{ "$2" }/g' /tmp/test.txt
```

Here, `$1{ "$2" }` is interpreted as "the `$2` key of the `%1` hash".

Put braces around the `$1` variable to disambiguate the expansion:

```sh
perl -pi -e 's/name(\s+)"(.*)"/name${1}{ "$2" }/g' /tmp/test.txt
# ..................................^.^
```

or escape the open brace

```sh
perl -pi -e 's/name(\s+)"(.*)"/name$1\{ "$2" }/g' /tmp/test.txt
# ...................................^
```

Or, use the the `\K` operator

```sh
perl -pi e 's/name\s+\K(".*")/{ $1 }/' test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming just the one pair of double quotes, and not limited to a `perl` solution ...

One idea using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/("[^"]*")/{ \1 }/' test.txt
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex (and capture groups)
- `("[^"]*")` - (capture group) match a `"` + 0-or-more `non-"` characters + `"`
- `{ \1 }` - replace the match with `{`  + capture group +  `}`

This generates:

```
name           { "Test Program" }
```

Once satisfied the results are correct you can add the `-i` flag to have the change made to the source file, eg:

```
$ cat test.txt
name           "Test Program"

$ sed -Ei 's/("[^"]*")/{ \1 }/' test.txt

$ cat test.txt
name           { "Test Program" }
```

---

Assuming we need to verify match for the `name` string ...

```
sed -E 's/([[:space:]]*name[[:space:]]+)("[^"]*")/\1{ \2 }/' test.txt
```

Where:

- `([[:space:]]*name[[:space:]]+)` - (1st capture group) is 0-or-more spaces + `name` + 1-or-more spaces
- `("[^"]*")` - (2nd capture group) same explanation as before
- `\1{ \2 }` - 1st capture group + `{`  + 2nd capture group +  `}`

Sample data file:

```
$ cat test.txt
name           "Test Program"
  name         "Test Program"
boat           "Test Program"
names          "Test Program"

$ sed -E 's/([[:space:]]*name[[:space:]]+)("[^"]*")/\1{ \2 }/' test.txt
name           { "Test Program" }
  name         { "Test Program" }
boat           "Test Program"
names          "Test Program"
```

Comment: Thanks!  Regarding 'sed -E 's/([[:space:]]*name[[:space:]]+)("[^"]*")/\1{ \2 }/' test.txt', any way to modify that to get the edits to happen in place?  Right now it's outputting the resulst to the screen.  Ultimately I want to pass a bunch of files to the command and have them run on each of them.

Comment: @Dave  yes, you can get the edit done to the file ... as mentioned, add the `-i` flag (see example - above - `sed -Ei ...`)

Answer (score 0):

Try with sed:

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/^name[ ]\+/name       { /g' | sed 's/["][ ]*$/" }/g'
```

Comment: THis outputs 'name           "Test Program" }' to the screen, but I want 'name           { "Test Program" }'.  Also, any way to get the changes to happen directly in the file without outputting them to the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `perl` command:

```sh
perl -i -pe 's/(name\s+)("[^"]+")/$1 { $2 }/' file

cat file

name            { "Test Program" }
```

Or this `sed`:

```sh
sed -i.bak -E 's/(name[[:blank:]]+)("[^"]+")/\1 { \2 }/' file
```